# Stored procedure return value Db2

Tags: db2

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE A()
   LANGUAGE SQL
   RESULT SETS 1
   BEGIN
      DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
         SELECT id, name, dept, job FROM staff;
      OPEN C1;
   END

 CREATE PROCEDURE B()
   LANGUAGE SQL
   BEGIN
        Call a ;
   END
```

In programming, they don't use stored procedure for returning value (they use function). Why does DB2 support that way?

In my above case, how does the stored procedure B know c1 cursor from stored procedure A? If I declare a cursor (`c2 cursor`) in stored procedure B and send to stored procedure A. Stored procedure A has a parameter (`OUT c2 cursor`), so why must I write 'RESULT SETS 1' (Can't I omit that phrase), because I don't return any cursor from stored procedure A (I return by parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might benefit from some education and training about SQL PL.

If you prefer a paper book, get "Db2 SQL Procedural Language for Linux, Unix, and Windows" by Paul Yip, Drew Bradstock and others. ISBN 0-13-100772-6.

Stackoverflow is not a substitute for training and education.

You should ask separate questions for different topics.

Research Db2 'table functions' to learn how to return a table from a function.

Research Db2 'strongly typed cursors', and Db2 'weakly typed cursors' and pipelined functions, to learn how to exploit cursor parameters in routines. Understand the many restrictions and rules associated with these things, which cannot be conveyed by one example in one question. In particular, realise that SQL PL cursor parameters can only be fully manipulated by SQL PL and cannot currently be passed to other languages for processing (except jdbc which has support for consuming such cursors). So if your front end client is using C, C++, Python, Javascript, .Net, PHP etc, then you won't use SQL PL cursor parameters currently. You might use them inside Db2 SQL PL code however, depending on your skills and needs.

To consume a result set from a nested stored procedure, you need extra syntax. When returning a result-set from a stored-procedure the `dynamic result sets` clause is required when defining the procedure.  Returning a result set in this manner is understood by many different programming languages and frameworks, and by other RDBMS tools, so is the most general purpose method for returning data from an RDBMS to a 3rd Generation programming language. Other mechanisms can be built based on this technique.

All of this syntax is documented in the Db2 Knowledge Centre for your version and platform. One example cannot convey all possible syntax.

Here is an example, you will find many others online if you are competent with search.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE procA()
   LANGUAGE SQL 
   RESULT SETS 1
   BEGIN
      DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR 
         SELECT id, name, dept, job FROM staff;
      OPEN C1; 
   END 
@

set serveroutput on@ 

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE B() 
LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN
   declare sqlstate char(5) default '00000';
   declare v_rs result_set_locator varying;
   declare v_id smallint;
   declare v_dept smallint;
   declare v_name varchar(9);
   declare v_job char(5);
   Call procA() ;
   associate result set locator (v_rs) with procedure procA;
   allocate v_rscur cursor for result set v_rs;
   fetch from v_rscur into v_id, v_name, v_dept, v_job;
   while ( sqlstate = '00000') do
       -- do something with the values just fetched...
       -- i.e. process the data in the current row of the result-set
      call dbms_output.put_line('id:'||varchar(v_id)||' name: '||v_name||' dept: '||varchar(v_dept)||' job: '||v_job);
      -- in this example just write the data to the output stream
      fetch from v_rscur into v_id, v_name, v_dept, v_job;
   end while;
   return;
END
@
```

Comment: Actually, we do have an ability to access OUT cursor parameters from JDBC at least. [Retrieving data from cursor output parameters in JDBC applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=cspija-retrieving-data-from-cursor-output-parameters-in-jdbc-applications).

Comment: Accepted, answer clarified. It's unknown where IBM will go with that in future.

Comment: I actually learn more by examples on places like here than I do from textbooks. I simply cannot absorb the information in a book as quickly - if ever.